# What type of file does the openLayer/TileLayer/source require?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Map} from'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import Stamen from 'ol/source/Stamen';
import View from 'ol/View';
import {transform} from 'ol/proj';
import Zoomify from 'ol/source/Zoomify';
import Projection from 'ol/proj/Projection';
const hongkong =  transform([114.15769,22.28552], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

@Component({
  selector: 'app-own-tile',
  templateUrl: './own-tile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./own-tile.component.css']
})
export class OwnTileComponent implements OnInit {  
  map: Map;
  width = 512;
  height = 512;

constructor() 
{ 
}

  ngOnInit() {    
let url = '/assets/jp2';    
this.map = new Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: url
    })  
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 0
      })
    });

  }

}
```

My question is for the source part of the TileLayer: source, what kind of file do i need to provide, currently i have a folder with different raster images with name of the folder being in this order: (zoomlevel,x-coordinate,y-coordinate) but this gives me error and the error is:

TypeError: Cannot create property 'ol_lm' on string '/assets/jp2'

To solve this error i need the type i need to provide in source and would be helpful is i could get some insight on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Layer object needs a "source" object from the OpenLayers lib, which in your case should be an xyz source:

```
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile'
import XYZSource from 'ol/source/XYZ'

layers: [
    new TileLayer({
        source: new XYZSource({
            url: 'path/to/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.[png/jpg/etc]'
        })
    })
]
```